# Is there a sort of way to use Unit testing with django_tables2 with filters?

Tags: django, django-filter, django-tables2

I have sql requests and the results in **csv format**. I already have included the `ExportMixin` to be able to export in csv format and compare the results.

I didn't find a clue even after reading the documentation of django_tables2 on
https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I tried to integrate the basic unit testing with `TestCase` but couldn't apply all the filters to my queryset